# Image not showing on browser laravel

Tags: php, html, css, laravel

I am working on my project and i have to upload an image in my DB everything is working fine the the image is being uploaded to my given path but it not showing on browser here is my code can somebody please tell me what is the mistake that i am making.

**This is my controller file**

```
  public function store(Request $request){

        $this->validate($request,[
            'image' =>'required|image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg|max:4000',
        ]);

        $news = new News();


        if($request->hasFile($request->input('image'))){
            $file = $request->file('image');
            $extension = $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
            $filename = time().'.'.$extension;
            $file->move('assets_info/uploads/news/',$filename);
            $news->image = $filename;
        }

        $news->save();

        return redirect()->route('news.index')->with('success','News Added Successfully');


    }
```

**This is my View file**

```
<section class="news-section mt-5">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-9">
          <section class="">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-12">
                @foreach ( $allnewsObj as $news)
                <?php
                  $newsTitle = ($locale === 'en')? $news->title_english:$news->title_arabic;
                  $newsContent = ($locale === 'en')? $news->content_english:$news->content_arabic;
                ?>
                <a href="{{route('news_details',$news->id)}}">
                  <div class="right-news right-news2 bg-greyish my-3">
                    <img src="{{asset('assets_info/uploads/news/',$news->image)}}" class="img-fluid">
                    <div class="content-news">
                      <h4>{{$newsTitle}}</h4>
                      <p><?php echo $newsContent; ?></p>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </a>
    
                @endforeach
              </div>
            </div>
            <h4 class="bg-greyish p-2  mb-5 text-end h4-news">
            <a href="#" class="">More</a>
          </h4>
          </section>
      </div>

      <div class="col-md-3">
        <div class="">
          <h4>Trending News</h4>
          @foreach ( $trendingNewsObj as $item )
          <ul class="ul-news">
            <li><a href="{{route('news_details',$item->id)}}">{{$item->title_english}}</a></li>
          </ul>        
          @endforeach
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: What is the absolute path of the successfully uploaded image?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure your file is being uploaded?
According to your controller code

```
$request->hasFile()
```

has wrong parameter provided. The parameter should be the name of the file field, not the file being uploaded.
Change it to

```
$request->hasFile('image')
```

See here:
https://laraveldaily.com/requests-has-and-hasfile/

Answer (score 0):

**At first change your Controller**

```
$file->move('assets_info/uploads/news/',$filename);
```

to

```
$file->move(public_path('uploads/news/'), $filename);
```

Here is the full source code of your controller, You should update your controller like this,

```
public function store(Request $request){

    $this->validate($request,[
        'image' =>'required|image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg|max:4000',
    ]);

    $news = new News();

    if ($request->file('image')) {
        $file = $request->file('image');
        $filename = date('YmdHi').$file->getClientOriginalName();

        $file->move(public_path('uploads/news/'), $filename);

        $news->image = $filename;
    }

    $news->save();

    return redirect()->route('news.index')->with('success','News Added Successfully');
}
```

And then update your view file

```
<img src="{{asset('assets_info/uploads/news/',$news->image)}}" class="img-fluid">
```

to

```
<img src="{{url('uploads/news/'.$news->image)}}" class="img-fluid">
```

And Here is the full source code of your updated view file,

```
<section class="news-section mt-5">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-9">
          <section class="">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-12">
                @foreach ( $allnewsObj as $news)
                <?php
                  $newsTitle = ($locale === 'en')? $news->title_english:$news->title_arabic;
                  $newsContent = ($locale === 'en')? $news->content_english:$news->content_arabic;
                ?>
                <a href="{{route('news_details',$news->id)}}">
                  <div class="right-news right-news2 bg-greyish my-3">

                    <img src="{{utl('uploads/news/'.$news->image)}}" class="img-fluid">

                    <div class="content-news">
                      <h4>{{$newsTitle}}</h4>
                      <p><?php echo $newsContent; ?></p>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </a>
    
                @endforeach
              </div>
            </div>
            <h4 class="bg-greyish p-2  mb-5 text-end h4-news">
            <a href="#" class="">More</a>
          </h4>
          </section>
      </div>

      <div class="col-md-3">
        <div class="">
          <h4>Trending News</h4>
          @foreach ( $trendingNewsObj as $item )
          <ul class="ul-news">
            <li><a href="{{route('news_details',$item->id)}}">{{$item->title_english}}</a></li>
          </ul>        
          @endforeach
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    
  </div>
</section>
```